# newenvironment enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I'd like to get a list with the label `$\mathscr{G}_1$`, where `G_1` is the first item in the list.

If I use

```
\newenvironment{enumeratescr}{\begin{enumerate}
                    [labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*,
                    label=$\mathscr{G}_1:$, noitemsep]}
                    {\end{enumerate}}
```

then all the items in the list start with `G_1`. How do I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 10):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{enumeratescr}
  {\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     label=$\mathscr{G}_{\arabic*}$:,
                     noitemsep
                    ]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

The current item number can be accessed with `\arabic*` (or other number representation commands).

The colon should go *outside* the formula, as it's not part of it. Take the habit of writing `\mathcal{X}` or `\mathbf{A}` and not `\mathcal X`.

(And, please, don't use non standard commands in a code snippet unless you provide also their definition or the packages necessary for them: nobody can know what `\mathscr` is supposed to do, as it's not a standard command.)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot to change \mscr to \mathscr. That was indeed helpful.

Comment: @nearim Also `\mathscr` is not a standard command. :)

Comment: How to continue the counter of enumeration whenever this enviornment is called again from the previous.

Comment: @nichas The `enumitem` package offers `resume`. There is an example in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463711/4427

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{enumeratescr}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[enumeratescr]{labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*,
                    label*=$\mathscr{G}_\arabic*$:, noitemsep}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumeratescr}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{enumeratescr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the label with the regular `enumitem` syntax:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={$\mathscr{G}_{\arabic*}$:}]
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item FooBar
\end{enumerate}
```